# “latex missing } inserted” error message in equation

Tags: equations, formatting, amsmath

I have a slightly complex, long section of equations in my latex document, but from what I can see I think it is programmed correctly. When I compile the document, I get the error

> "./ThesisDraft1.tex:111: Display math should end with $$. ^ l.111 ...dD}{dt} = \frac{\Gamma \times A}{x$^{2}$}"

The error starts at the first line of the equation, and if I comment out that line, moves to the second line of the equation and crashes, etc. I have tried commenting out the entire equation block and the document compiles with no problem, so I know it's a problem with this equation block. I have another equation earlier in the document, but that compiles with no problem.

Here is the code block:

```
   \begin{displaymath}
   \frac{dD}{dt} = \frac{\Gamma \times A}{x$^{2}$}
   dD = \frac{\Gamma \times A}{$x^{2}$}dt
   \int{dD} = \int_0^21hrs  \frac{\Gamma \times A}{x$^{2}$}dt 
   \int{dD} = \frac{\Gamma}{$x^{2}$} \int_0^21hrs A dt = \frac{\Gamma \times A$_{0}$}                       {x$^{2}$} \int_0^21hrs exp$^{-\delta t}$ dt
   \end{displaymath}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: remove the `$` you are already in math mode

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Also, not sure about the `0^21hrs`. Is that intended to be `0^{2} 1hrs`, or `0^{21} hrs`, or something else?

Comment: Thanks David, that worked! Any idea how I can close out this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved in the comments by removing the superfluous $